# Searching a list of strings to return only those strings that match another input list of strings in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a c# Linq solution.

Given a list of strings, lets call the list S

```
"alan.foo", "bob.htm", "dave.tea", "other.yuy"
```

Then, also given another list of strings, lets call it X

```
".foo", ".htm",  ".tea"
```

What is the linq expression to return only those records in S that end with the strings in X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = S.Where(x=> X.Any(y=>x.EndsWith(y)));
```

If you want to ignore case:

```
var result = S.Where(x => X.Any(y => x.EndsWith(y, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: @AlanSimes I tested it and it worked, for the full code sample, see the answer of `Soner...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
List<string> S = new List<string>() { "alan.foo", "bob.htm", "dave.tea", "other.yuy" };
List<string> X = new List<string>() { ".foo", ".htm", ".tea" };

var newlist = S.Where(n => X.Any(s => n.EndsWith(s)));

foreach (var item in newlist)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
alan.foo
bob.htm
dave.tea
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/NuVvUc).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "alan.foo", "bob.htm", "dave.tea", "other.yuy" };
var list2 = new List<string> { ".foo", "htm", ".adf" };

List<string> list3 = (from n in list1
                    from l in list2
                    where n.EndsWith(l)
                    select n).ToList();
```

Hope it helps.